# How to fix the datetime ValueError "time data does not match format"

Tags: python, datetime

I am getting a ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %) error when running this spider. I double checked all my xpaths to ensure they were pointing to the correct element and they are.

I am trying to convert the text I get back into a datetime object so I can use the date.year. Any insight or direction would be much appreciated.

```
date = link.xpath("./text()").get()
                date = datetime.strptime(str(date), '%B %d, %Y')
                year = date.year
```

The date in this case equates to January 3, 2022
[enter image description here][1]
picture for reference
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9NdF.png

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question) ...[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) ... 
[You should not post code as an image because:...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2823755)

Comment: `str(date)` must not be what you think it is - when you inspected it what did you find?  Print `str(date)` just before you try to *convert* it. `datetime.datetime.strptime('January 3, 2022', '%B %d, %Y')` works for me.